# Ajax does not appear to work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to use Ajax in ASP.NET Core, but the request does not go to the controller. I use VS 2017 and ASP.NET Core 2.1.

View:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buttonDemo1').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/demo/demo1',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result1').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script> 

<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="demo1" id="buttonDemo1" />
            <br />
            <span id="result1">

            </span>
        </form>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
[Route("Demo1")]
public IActionResult Demo1()
{
    return new JsonResult("DEmo1");
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

update:
I test this code and 
it work in my Project:

```
     <script>
            function loadDoc() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "/Demo/demo1", true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
    </script>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you have a RoutePrefix attribute on the controller? What's your controllers name?

Comment: `[Route("Demo")]
public class DemoController : Controller`

Comment: Ok. So `/Demo/Demo1` should work. Is your View-File or html file in the root `/` of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a problem with the relative URL: I would generate the URL with the URL Action Helper from c# In your view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = '@Url.Action("Demo1", "Demo")';

    $('#buttonDemo1').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#result1').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```